# Ruby select filename from array of filenames

Tags: ruby

I have an array of filenames in ruby.
I want to select the filename that contains a specific string in it

for example

```
array = ["/some/place/once.txt", "/some/place/two.txt","/some/place/three.txt"]
```

and i want to select only the filename that has the word `"two"` in it

so I want to get `filename = array.select { |e| e.include? "two" }`

but for some reason filename contains everything that is in array.
How to make it work?

Comment: It should work, and I can't reproduce your problem. What else is there between setting filename and checking filename?

Comment: nothing, i have the array first line (i receive it as a parameter) and the filename selection second line

Comment: Lena, try copy pasting in the code from your question into a new IRB console. You will see that it produces the expected result. Therefore there must be something else going on in your code that you're not showing us.

Comment: Do you want the file name and not the entire dir path? If so: array.select { |e| e.include? "two" }.map { |p| p.split("/").last } Otherwise your code seems to be working

Comment: @maxpleaner it ended up being cursive " that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Given this data:

```
array = ["/some/place/once.txt", "/some/place/two.txt","/some/place/three.txt"]
```

You can always find all matching entries with `grep` and just take the first:

```
array.grep(/two/).first
# => ["/some/place/two.txt"]
```

Or you can always scan using `find`:

```
array.find { |s| s.include?('two') }
# => "/some/place/two.txt"
```

Using `select` should produce an array result of *all* matches, but is otherwise identical. Your behaviour cannot be reproduced.